# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^n\cos{\frac{a}{p^k}}$ where $p\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, infinite-product

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\cos{\dfrac{a}{p^k}}, p\in\mathbb{N}$$I can use double angle formulae to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\cos{\dfrac{a}{2^k}}=\dfrac{\sin a}{a}$$
But I wonder the evaluation when $p=3,4,5\cdots$ 
$$$$The question might be complex-analysis-related.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\cos{\dfrac{a}{2^k}}=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ no $x$ on LHS

Comment: look at the answer to my first (!) question on this site. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918281/generalizing-a-trig-identity

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks. my question seems to be duplicated.